# Can I add background colors in html?

Tags: html

I'd like to know if I can add background colors instead of background images because they sometimes don't show :). Usually, I would just use the background-image: URL(""); like usual, but again, sometimes they wont show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is not bad at all to determine a background colour when working with background images.

```css
div {
    background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/500/green");
    background-color: black;
    height:500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>123</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add both the `background-color` and `background-image` on the same element for the color to serve as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

You can change background with css especially,  but here some example of code, I hope   it will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<p>You can use custom background color also with css</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to coding :). I also use a crappy school Chromebook so maybe that's why it didn't work.

Comment: Just try to study correctly,  u can study here,  https://codepen.io/, there is many example for you  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background-color` or just `background` property. There are 2 ways of doing it. Either you can use use css using the `<style>` tag, or you can just edit the css in the html element itself if you just want to add 1 line of css. Example - `<div style="background: red;"></div>`.